# Calculate forces on atoms from potential energy of system and position of atoms

Tags: molecular-dynamics, differential-equations

### Background

I am using a neural network to calculate the potential energy of atoms in a configuration and then adding energy of all atoms to compare it with the true energy of the configuration(label) to update the weights.

I am doing so for 10000 configurations of 100 atoms each for liquid Argon at 100K.

**Note** I don't have the actual energy of each atom and only the energy of the configuration.

### Problem

I need to calculate the forces on each atom to see if the sum of forces for all the atoms is zero in X,Y,Z axis. In case it is not I want to find out how off is it from zero.

How do I calculate the force on atoms using their position and potential energy for a given trajectory. I know I need to do $\frac{dE}{dr}$ but what should be my E and r. Also since I don,t a formula for E(r), what should my $dE$ and $dr$ be respectively?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you have two methods to calculate the energy of a configuration: (1) a neural network and (2) a more standard algorithm. Do you want to check that the forces add up to zero for 1, or for 2? Is the liquid argon being simulated in a container, or is it a droplet being simulated as it floats weightlessly in space?

Comment: @fireball.1 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/99760/41556 I think I have brought this up before, but if you are going to cross post a question, link the other versions of it in your post. It helps to avoid wasting people's time repeating answers.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, the force acting on particle $i$ is just $-\nabla E(\vec{r}_i)$ (note the minus sign), where $\nabla$ is the gradient operator and $\vec{r}_i$ is the position of particle $i$. However, note that this expression assumes that we are dealing with *conservative* forces. But if that's the case, the energy is conserved *by definition*, which means that the forces *must* average to 0.

However, to answer your question, I guess you could try to numerically estimate the force acting on each particle by displacing it along each axis, recomputing the energy and taking the numerical derivative by calculating

$$
F_\alpha \approx - \frac{E(\vec{r}_i + \delta \vec{\alpha}) - E(\vec{r}_i)}{\delta \alpha}
$$

where $\alpha = x$, $y$ or $z$. You should first do this for several values of $\delta$ in order to choose the optimal value and then compute the force acting on *each* particle for a given configuration.